# Need to remove underline on hover and on focus MUI TimePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Cannot find a way to remove underline when using material-ui TimePicker and overriding styles.

Here is how i am overriding styles:

```
const muiTimePickerStyle = createTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiTextField: {
            root: {
                width: "100%",
                '&:after': {
                    underline: "none",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                }
            }
        },
        MuiInput: {
            root: {
                borderRadius: 0,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                border: '1px solid pink',
                fontSize: 16,
                padding: '10px 12px',
                width: '100%',
                underline: "none",
                textDecoration: "none",
                '&:hover': {

                }
            },
            underline: {
                underline: "none",
                '&:hover': {

                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-haze-ordsz8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for. I've added the after effect too if you wanted to remove the blue line when active.

```
          underline: {
              '&:hover:not(.Mui-disabled):before': {
                borderBottom: 'none'
              },
              '&:after': {
                borderBottom: 'none'
              }
          }
```

Enjoy